# Correct hostname doesn't change in entire system

Tags: debian, hostname

I have a very strange problem with my hostname on Debian 7+. I've changed the `hostname` on my new server but for some reason it doesn't change in wierd places. Right now I get the old `hostname` when I login using SSH *AND* all my cron emails send the emails as **root@old.hostname.com**.

`/etc/hosts` has the correct new hostname (**new.hostname.com**)

`/etc/sysconfig/network` has the correct new hostname (**new.hostname.com**)

`hostname` shows the correct new hostname (**new.hostname.com**)

`hostname -A` and `hostname --fqdn` shows the correct new hostname (**new.hostname.com**)

Where else can I look to see if there's a missconfiguration somewhere?

This is the example welcome text when logging in using SSH:

```
login as: root
root@new.hostname.com's password:
Linux old.hostname.com 2.6.32-042stab094.7 #1 SMP Wed Oct 22 12:43:21 MSK 2014 x86_64
```

Comment: Did you restart your system after changing the hostname?

Comment: I can't explain this... but a reboot didn't do it but a hard server power off and power on magically made the hostname appear correct. So wierd! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Powering the server off and then powering it on again forced it to update the hostname.

A regular reboot would probably do it as well in most cases.

Comment: Never underestimate the tenacity of a caching name server. :)

Comment: I'd love to know what service was caching the old name. I don't want to have to reboot a production server to fix the hostname. It's confusing my logging system, but it's mostly cosmetic. Highly annoying though.